# Python multiprocessing, statsmodels and Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python

I am trying to use the statsmodels package in a python multiprocessing process. It fails with:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

Without the import for statsmodels it works fine (but I do need it!). I've tried installing statsmodels from pip and conda; same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be due to duplicate copies of mkl_intel_thread.dll in my Python environment.